# I'm looking for the VBA code to change an object's position

Tags: vba, position, powerpoint

I should begin by saying that I am VERY new to VBA coding and coding in general.

I have a ball object that I'm trying to move through a maze. I need to figure out the code to change the object's position along the X and Y axes after completion of an animation which is triggered by the clicking of an arrow button triggering a macro.

I'm trying to use a translation variable to re-define the position of Picture 2 (the ball) after the arrow click. The following is a snippet of code I've written, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
Dim PosOld As Integer
Console.WriteLine (PosOld)

Dim PosNew As Integer
Console.WriteLine (PosNew)
```

'Defines the ball's new position

```
Set PosNew = PosOld - 1
Picture2.animate().translationX(-1).translationY (0)
```

Comment: Looks like you're using VB.NET and not VBA?

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working" - please be more specific.  What happens - or doesn't happen - when you run your code, and how does that differ from what you expect to happen?

Comment: The code doesn't update to the new position. A click of the arrow makes the ball move, but when I click it again, the ball restarts from the original position without translating to the new position.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` is not valid in VBA, so what language are you actually using?

Comment: I'm trying to use VBA, but I'm synthesizing my code from a few different message boards, so there is bound to be some overlap.

Comment: There's no way your code compiles as VBA or runs, so "A click of the arrow makes the ball move" seems unlikely?

Comment: Well, I defined the motion path outside of the VBA code using the Animation interface of the PowerPoint program, and then I mapped the macro to call it in the animation pane, so yes, it does work.

Comment: Cross-posted at answers.microsoft.com. Cross-posting etiquette: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95615/cross-posting-etiquette

Comment: *but when I click it again, the ball restarts from the original position without translating to the new position.* So you should have a variable to be able to write down the last position or get the starting position this time, right?

Comment: Your code is completely copied from others, and VBA has nothing to do with it. 
`animate().translationX(-1).translationY (0)`
I wonder how you can work in PowerPoint, I am afraid you are not telling the truth! The code you have given is not corresponding to the situation you described. If you do not honestly confess, we really can not help you.